# Java Swing- adding a label below a single line bottom border in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want the label Hotel Management System *copyright* 2016 to appear below the `MatteBorder` at the bottom and also centered. I have tried `copyrightL.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);`but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
 public class Admin_hs extends JFrame {

JButton bking_btn= new JButton("Bookings");
JButton fd_btn= new JButton("Financial Data");
JButton ctm_btn= new JButton("Customers");
JButton room_btn= new JButton("Rooms");
JButton adc_btn= new JButton("Additional Costs");
JButton endb_btn= new JButton("Ending Bookings");

//Images
JLabel bking_img= new JLabel();
JLabel fd_img= new JLabel();
JLabel ctm_img= new JLabel();
JLabel room_img= new JLabel();
JLabel adc_img= new JLabel();
JLabel endb_img= new JLabel();
JLabel copyrightL = new JLabel("Hotel Management System \u00a9 2016");

///Panels

JPanel pnl1= new JPanel();
JPanel pnl= new JPanel((new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)));

///Constructors

public Admin_hs(){
    this.setTitle("Welcome Admin!");
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    ///Setting a layout

    pnl1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth= GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.fill= gbc.HORIZONTAL;

     gbc.weightx = 1;                       // ADD THIS LINE so it uses all the existing window size in x direction
     pnl1.add(pnl);                         // ADD THIS LINE


    pnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gc= new GridBagConstraints();

    ///First Column of Grid


    gc.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 6, 6);
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.weighty = 0.5;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;

    pnl.add(bking_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    pnl.add(fd_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    pnl.add(ctm_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    pnl.add(room_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    pnl.add(adc_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 5;
    pnl.add(endb_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 8;
    pnl.add(copyrightL, gc);


    /////second column of grid



    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    bking_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/booking.jpg"));
    pnl.add(bking_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    fd_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/fd.jpg"));
    pnl.add(fd_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    ctm_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/guest.jpg"));
    pnl.add(ctm_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    room_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/room.jpg"));
    pnl.add(room_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    adc_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/adc.jpg"));
    pnl.add(adc_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 5;
    endb_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/endb.png"));
    pnl.add(endb_img, gc);

    //copyrightL.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    //copyrightL.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    //pnl.add(copyrightL);

    pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

     this.add(pnl1,gbc); 


     }

}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Admin_main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Admin_hs adm= new Admin_hs();

    adm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    adm.pack();
    adm.setVisible(true);
    adm.setSize(780,520);

    }

}
```

Here is how it currently looks:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

It worked for me in this way:

```
public class Admin_hs extends JFrame {

JButton bking_btn= new JButton("Bookings");
JButton fd_btn= new JButton("Financial Data");
JButton ctm_btn= new JButton("Customers");
JButton room_btn= new JButton("Rooms");
JButton adc_btn= new JButton("Additional Costs");
JButton endb_btn= new JButton("Ending Bookings");

//Images
JLabel bking_img= new JLabel();
JLabel fd_img= new JLabel();
JLabel ctm_img= new JLabel();
JLabel room_img= new JLabel();
JLabel adc_img= new JLabel();
JLabel endb_img= new JLabel();
JLabel copyrightL = new JLabel("Hotel Management System \u00a9 2016");


///Panels

JPanel pnl1= new JPanel();
JPanel pnl2= new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

///Constructors

public Admin_hs(){
    this.setTitle("Welcome Admin!");
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    ///Setting a layout



    pnl1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill= gbc.HORIZONTAL;


    GridBagConstraints gc= new GridBagConstraints();

    ///First Column of Grid


    gc.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 6, 6);
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.weighty = 0.5;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;

    pnl1.add(bking_btn, gc);


    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    pnl1.add(fd_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    pnl1.add(ctm_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    pnl1.add(room_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    pnl1.add(adc_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 5;
    pnl1.add(endb_btn, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 8;
    pnl1.add(copyrightL, gc);


    /////second column of grid



    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    bking_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/booking.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(bking_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    fd_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/fd.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(fd_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    ctm_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/guest.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(ctm_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    room_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/room.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(room_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    adc_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/adc.jpg"));
    pnl1.add(adc_img, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 5;
    endb_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/endb.png"));
    pnl1.add(endb_img, gc);


    pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

     gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        pnl2.add(copyrightL, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(pnl1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(pnl2, gbc);

    }
```

}

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

The buttons have somehow shifted to the left. That's fine for me as I had to move them to the left for some reason. How can I get their corresponding images to the left though? I mean, how can I get the the images closer to the buttons to the left?

Comment: So the desired output is having the copyright statement below the grey line. Correct ?

Comment: Is my answer what you are after or do you require any additional help?

Comment: @user3437460 yes, that's the desired output

Comment: @Dan It seems to work partly as it's getting my other panels(the one which contains the buttons) disarranged.. Would be grateful to you if you could show me how it works through my codes

Comment: Sure let me edit my answer. I will replace the images though

Comment: I edited the answer with your code. You can mess around with the weightx and weighty to tweak the current layout out so it is how you want it

Comment: Is this what you are after?

Comment: P.S. I edited the code so that the copyright at the bottom remains a constant vertical height

Comment: How is this different than your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634655/java-swing-gui-adding-a-single-border-at-the-bottom??? Just add the label with a Border to the SOUTH of the BorderLayout of the frame. Add your other panel top the center.

Comment: The line probably ought to say, "Hotel Management System created by many, many Stack Overflow answers, copyright 2016 - 2019".

Comment: Do you have what you want now?

Comment: @Dan Thanks a lot for your help.. I edited the body of my question(added the codes which worked for me and also an image of how it looks now) Would be pleased if you could show me how I can get the images to the left and also all the buttons of the same size

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That made me laugh. Indeed, really thankful to all the Stack Overflow users for helping newbies in Java

Comment: No problem. Another thought which you might work with is instead of using two panels just create a border above the label instead. That is if you're interested in approaching the problem in a different way.

Comment: @Dan That would be quite time consuming to attempt to address the problem differently.. I have been able to get the buttons the same size using `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20)` by the way.. I just need to get the images to the left that is closer to their buttons

Comment: If you look here [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12902770/4601149) it will explain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to do this would be to use code similar to this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()), testPanel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    private GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Something"), label2 = new JLabel("Something Else");

    Test() {
        super("Example Frame");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildGUI();

        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(testPanel, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        add(testPanel2, c);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildGUI() {
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        testPanel.add(label1, c);

        testPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        testPanel2.add(label2, c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

In this code, there are two JPanels, each with a JLabel on it. The first panel has a border on the bottom and the second panel is placed underneath. You can do this by setting a layout on your JFrame You could adopt this idea to work with your code.

With your code, it would look like this.

**Admin_main**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Admin_main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Admin_hs adm= new Admin_hs();

        adm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        adm.pack();
        adm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Admin_hs**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Admin_hs extends JFrame {
    JButton bking_btn= new JButton("Bookings");
    JButton fd_btn= new JButton("Financial Data");
    JButton ctm_btn= new JButton("Customers");
    JButton room_btn= new JButton("Rooms");
    JButton adc_btn= new JButton("Additional Costs");
    JButton endb_btn= new JButton("Ending Bookings");

    //Images
    JLabel bking_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel fd_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel ctm_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel room_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel adc_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel endb_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel copyrightL = new JLabel("Hotel Management System \u00a9 2016");

    ///Panels

    JPanel pnl1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()), pnl2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    ///Constructors

    public Admin_hs(){
        setTitle("Welcome Admin!");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        ///Setting a layout

        pnl1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        gbc.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 6, 6);
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        pnl1.add(bking_btn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        pnl1.add(fd_btn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        pnl1.add(ctm_btn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        pnl1.add(room_btn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        pnl1.add(adc_btn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        pnl1.add(endb_btn, gbc);


        /////second column of grid
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.fill= GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Smiley.gif");
        Image image2 = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50, 0);
        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(image2);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        bking_img.setIcon(icon2);
        pnl1.add(bking_img, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        fd_img.setIcon(icon2);
        pnl1.add(fd_img, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        ctm_img.setIcon(icon2);
        pnl1.add(ctm_img, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        room_img.setIcon(icon2);
        pnl1.add(room_img, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        adc_img.setIcon(icon2);
        pnl1.add(adc_img, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        endb_img.setIcon(icon2);
        pnl1.add(endb_img, gbc);

        pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(pnl1, gbc);

        gbc.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        pnl2.add(copyrightL, gbc);

        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(pnl2, gbc);
    }
}
```

This produces this

[image]